# Object parent is the object itself on $object->save(); $this->parent->parent->... === $this

Tags: php, laravel-5, shared-hosting, php-5.6

First of all, sorry if the title is a little bit vague but it's the best I could come up with.

My problem:
I have several tasks, each task can have subtasks.
When a task is created it sets the finished_at field in the DB in the method recursiveParentUpdater(). For some reason my new task after saving is his own parent (but not in the database, still NULL).

Eg.

```php
$task = new Task;
// set my properties
$task->save(); // let's say ID = 5

$task->parent->parent->parent->...->id === 5 // I have no idea why this happens
```

Then the $task->recursiveParentUpdater() uses $this->parent to get itself and screw it all up.
This only happens when a new task is created, when deleting there is no more $task to parent itself.

It all used to work fine (local and shared hosting), 2 days later without having touched it I encountered this problem (only on shared hosting, local still no problems).
My Debian machine is still running PHP5.6, shared-host supports 5.6 and 7 but it changes nothing.

My database schema **UPDATED (added 'show create table tasks')**

```php
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->date('deadline_date')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->time('deadline_time')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->datetime('finished_at')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('tasks')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });

or

 tasks| CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`deadline_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`deadline_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
`finished_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `tasks_parent_id_foreign` (`parent_id`),
KEY `tasks_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `tasks_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `tasks` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `tasks_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=337 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

My model (parts that are relevant)

```php
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');
}

public function hasParent() {
    return (!is_null($this->parent)) ? true : false;
}

public function hasChildren() {
    return (count($this->children) > 0) ? true : false;
}

public function updateParentFinishedStatus() {
    function recursiveParentUpdater($task) {
        if ($task->hasParent()) {
            $task->parent->setFinishedAt(date('d-m-Y H:i:s'));

            foreach ($task->parent->children as $child) {
                if (!$child->isFinished()) {
                    $task->parent->setFinishedAt(null);
                    break;
                }
            }
            $task->parent->save();

            if ($task->parent->hasParent()) recursiveParentUpdater($task->parent);
        }
    }

    recursiveParentUpdater($this);
}
```

My controller

```php
public function postCreate(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'string|required',
        'description' => 'string',
        'ptid' => 'integer|exists:tasks,id',
        'deadline_date' => 'date|after:yesterday|required_with:deadline_time',
        'deadline_time' => 'dateformat:H:i',
    ]);

    $task = new Task;
    $task->setTitle($request->get('title'));
    $task->setDescription($request->get('description'));
    $task->setDeadline($request->get('deadline_date'), $request->get('deadline_time'));

    if (!empty($request->get('ptid'))) {
        $task->parent()->associate($request->get('ptid'));
    }

    $task->user()->associate(Auth::user());

    $task->save();

    $task->updateParentFinishedStatus();

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function getDelete(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'tid' => 'integer|required|exists:tasks,id',
    ]);

    $task = Task::where('id', $request->get('tid'))->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

    $task->delete();

    $task->updateParentFinishedStatus();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: You should provide the actual schema for your table as SQL instead and include the relevant data so that we can try to reproduce the problem, but so far it sounds like you're setting the `parent_id` as the `id` of the newly created task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure why it was a problem on the host and not on my local machine, but this what fixed it.
I changed this line of code

```php
public function hasParent() {
    return (!is_null($this->parent)) ? true : false;
}
```

to

```php
public function hasParent() {
    return (!is_null($this->parent_id)) ? true : false;
}
```